# What does >var mean?

Tags: javascript

Please see [this page](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html). The two for loops have `>var`. What is the `>` doing there?

Comment: It means that somebody didn't try out their examples before clicking the "Publish" button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a typo. That won't run like `>var`. It would cause an syntax error like `Unexpected Token >`

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JavaScript, and will produce a syntax error.

It looks like that the site owner used a search-and-replace operation, without looking at his code:

```
<span class="phpKeyword">for<span class="phpOperator">(</span></span>>var
                                                                    ^^
```